# How to fill an Array with response of an http request?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to fill a JavaScript array with a few objects, caught by an http request. Unfortunatly I don't know which ArrayMethod I should use. I tried splice(), but it seems like it doesn't accept variables (for the http output) as an input. Is there anybody who has some tips or knows how to do it?

In my code example I want to fill the Array with the content, shown in "id01".

Thanks for your help!

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>


<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var url = "https://waterfallexpress2020.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myTutorial.txt"; 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    myFunction(myArr);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true); 
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) { 

  var out = "";
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + 
    arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;   
  return out;
}

var test =[];

test.splice(0,0,myFunction); //DOESN'T FILL MY ARRAY WITH THE OUTPUT OF myFunction()

document.write(test);

</script>
```

Comment: You're calling [``splice()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) incorrectly. Also, you should probably be populating ``test`` inside ``myFunction()``, where it populates ``id01``. Also, the innerHTML of ``id01`` will be a string. To put that string into the ``test`` array is simple: ``test.push( out )``. Or just ``test = [ out ]``.

Answer (score 1):

You made an asynchronous request, so you will have to wait for response. You did it with the xmlhttp request and the statement `myFunction(myArr)`.
So in order to keep this returning response, you should initiate variable before your request and fill it with the response:

```
var test;
...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
...
test = myFunction(myArr);
...
document.write(test);
```

Be careful with splice, it create new instance of initial variable and it losts getters and setters.